# Issue Capture iframe-part of web screenshot using javascript html2canvas- Cross domain iframe capture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

I am getting a blank screen for the iframe part of div in the screenshot. The iframe makes a call to tableau server, which is hosted on a different server.

> Doing more research i found out that this is a cross-domain iframe load issue. [Doc:](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html) has clearly specified the limitation!

I have tried finding some answers, but no luck yet.

Is there a way to overcome this?

-Regards

Comment: The documentation shows a `useCORS` parameter – but that seems to be for images, not sure if that works for iframes as well. (Plus, the provider of the iframe content would have to enable CORS on their end.) Other than that, you can only proxy the content, so that the script sees it as coming from your server.

Comment: Do you have some java proxy samples, as i feel that is the only possible way now!